# Use same TableViewCell in different ViewControllers

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have two ViewControllers and both of them have TableView and custom TableViewCell. Can I use same Custom cell in two different tableViews of two different ViewControllers?

Comment: Of course you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can,

If you're designing those in Storyboard, just copy the cell from one tableview to another tableview.

OR

If you have the Xib file for the CustomCell then in viewDidLoad() you can register the custom cell with the tableView in both viewControllers and can use it.

Thats it.

Comment: Hope you figured out the way how to do this, As this answer helps you and meant to help others, consider marking this answer as accepted.

Comment: Ok but why my question is downvoted? Do you know the reason? Is it unclear or unfair?

Comment: because your question doesn't show any effort and resarch